# How do I use a Personal Access Token with the Github API?

Tags: java, android, github

I have a personal access token for my Github account that I am trying to use to test an app that has to have the functionality of following/unfollowing other users. The problem for me, I am having a really hard time figuring out how I am even supposed to use my token or how to go about doing it.

I know from multiple other posts that you follow others with a PUT request on the Github API (which I can do with http requests in java), but the prerequisite is that you are already authenticated. In the documentation on Github, they use curl on a command line interface (https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), but that is not what I am wanting to do.

I am just generally lost as to what I should be looking for on how to go about doing this right now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Although the curl client is not the command you'll run in your application, it provides all the info you need, and shows a minimal working example of how to hit the API. Specifically, you'll need to attach a header to your request as they show. What HTTP client are you using in Android? The HTTP client you use will dictate how you add headers to your request. OkHttp is a good one to try if you don't have one yet.

Comment: I've never used java or it's HTTP libraries before, so I really don't understand how the curl command translates to an API call. Are there any resources I can read that would clarify that?

Comment: [Here's the curl man page.](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). There are lots of options, but all you need to know for now is that `curl http://foo` does a GET request to `http://foo`, and `curl -H "Authorization: bar" http://foo` makes a GET request with the header `Authorization` set to `bar`. (See the docs for `-H`.) This translates to an API call because that's what curl does. It makes API calls. You'll need to make an API call from your application using whichever HTTP library you choose, and you'll have to read that library's docs to see how to do things like add a header.